# Linux Failed to start couchbase-server : timed out

Tags: linux, server, couchbase

Linux is installed on my server. Couchbase is not functioning well on the server, so i just try to stop and start it

```
service couchbase-server stop
```

It will take to much time and in between my server connection getting lost, after again connected to server i checked the status of couchbase

```
service couchbase-server status
```

It will telling that the couchbase-server is not running. Now i am trying to start the couchbase-server as

```
service couchbase-server start
```

But it always displaying message

```
Failed to start couchbase-server:timed out
```

There are also two crash_log.bin and crash_log_v2.bin file in my logs directory.

Comment: I had a similar problem recently. I just did a reinstall (dpkg --purge and dpkg -i) and that seemed to do the trick. Maybe I got a corrupted deb file or something?

Comment: Hey @Matthew Groves, I found my solution, actually there is a deadlock occurred on my server. So that's why its not getting started. I simply restart my server. Now its getting worked.